How to prove no solution exists for this equation?
How can I prove that there are no positive integer solutions $(x, y)$ and prime $p$ satisfying the equation $(x+y)(x^2+y^2) = p(p + 2xy)$?
I made a c++ program to find out that there are no solutions but I don't have a rigorous proof.
Edit:
I proved that $\gcd(x,y) = 1$ (thanks to John Omielan) by assuming that $\gcd(x,y) = d$ then $x = {x_1}d$ and $y = {y_1}d$ then $d^3(x_1+y_1)(x_1^2+y_1^2) = p(p+2d^2{x_1}{y_1})$ then $d$ must occur in RHS at least 3 times. by dividing both sides by $d^3$ we can see that the RHS is not an integer hence the $\gcd(x,y)$ must be $1$

Where is this problem from?

I managed to prove that (a) $p\mid x^2+y^2$, (b) $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, (c) $x,y$ are coprime, (d) any two of the $x+y, x^2+y^2, 2xy$ are coprime, (e) $p\not\mid x$, $p\not\mid y$.

This is an interesting problem, that I've determined a solution to. However, unfortunately, your question currently doesn't meet the site's quality standards. Thus, before I provide an answer, please first edit the question to add some appropriate context, such as answering Aig's request about where the problem is from, your attempt to solve it analytically, etc. Thanks.

@JohnOmielan You are right. The problem is I got this problem from a discord server called mathematical Olympiad. It's a public server. So that's why I don't know how to write the source of the problem

Thanks for stating where you got the problem from. Please add that, along with whatever you tried yourself algebraically, to your question text.

Regarding including what you tried, can you prove, or at least include your attempts, that $\gcd(x,y)=1$ and $p\neq 2$? Those are the initial parts of my solution, and I suspect likely also of any other proof method.

I've been trying somethings and didn't reach anything useful I think. just a hint. Is it related to diaphontine equations?

Once you having $p \mid x^2+y^2$ and $\gcd(x,y)=1,$ you can forget that $p$ is a prime number.
It is sufficient to show that there is no triplet of positive integers $(x,y,z)$ such that $(x+y)(x^2+y^2)+(xy)^2 = z^2, z-xy|x^2+y^2,$ and $\gcd(x,y,z)=1.$

Wikipedia's Diophantine equation has it's "... an equation, typically a polynomial equation in two or more unknowns with integer coefficients, for which only integer solutions are of interest", so it applies. Re: a hint, let $\gcd(x,y)=d$ so $x=dx_1$, $y=dy_1$ & $\gcd(x_1,y_1)=1$. Then $d^3(x_1+y_1)(x_1^2+y_1^2)=p(p+2d^2x_1y_1)$. Note the LHS shows every prime factor of $d$ must occur on the RHS at least $3$ times. Can any prime $q\neq p$ have $q\mid d$? How about $p\mid d$? Please try at least this & add your results to your question.

we can divide by $d^{3}$ but The RHS will not be an integer unless $d = 1$ (correct me if that's wrong) So if that's right on the track we proved $\gcd(x,y) = 1$ so I can continue from here

That's basically correct. If $d$ has any prime factors, then the RHS won't be an integer when divided by $d^3$, so this mean that $d = 1$, i.e., $\gcd(x,y)=1$. Note this is an important part of my solution method, and I suspect likely any other ones as well, so please continue from there. It's a good start.

I think that's it after that. if $\gcd(x,y) = 1$ then $p\nmid x+y$ so $p\mid x+y$
But that's not the case because $\gcd(x^2,y^2) = 1$ too. so there are no valid integer solutions. If that's true I will edit the post with the solution. Thanks!

Thanks for trying but, unfortunately, it's not quite that simple. First, with your "then $p\nmid x+y$ so $p\mid x+y$", I assume the second part should be $p\mid x^2+y^2$. Regardless, having $\gcd(x,y)=1$ doesn't mean $p\nmid x+y$, e.g., for $p=5$, then $(x,y)\in{(1,4),(2,3)}$ has $\gcd(x,y)=1$ with $p\mid x+y$. The solution I have does first prove $p\nmid x+y$, and then also $p\nmid x^2+y^2$, but it uses several methods such as squares being non-negative, factoring and size issues. I suggest editing your post to just show, in your own words, $\gcd(x,y)=1$, and I'll then provide an answer.

Big hint for the case $p\nmid x+y$ (i.e. $p \mid x^2+y^2$): First wlog $x>y$. (1) $x^2+y^2 \equiv 0\pmod{p}$ implies $(x+y)^2 \equiv 2xy \pmod{p}$. (2) Setting $d = (x^2+y^2)/p$, we have $d(x+y) \equiv 2xy\pmod{p}$.  (3) From (1) and (2), we have $d \equiv x+y \pmod{p}$. (4) From the original equation, we can show that $p>x$. (5) From $d=(x^2+y^2)/p$ and (4), we have $d<2x$.(6) From (4) and (5), we have either $d=x+y$ or $d=x+y-p$.  (7) Finish the proof

@JohnOmielan I editted the post

As you've stated, for any positive integer solutions $(x, y)$ and prime $p$ satisfying
$$(x+y)(x^2+y^2) = p(p + 2xy) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
we have that $\gcd(x, y) = d = 1$. To show this, using
$$x = dx_1, \; y = dy_1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
in \eqref{eq1A}, we get
$$d^3(x_1 + y_1)(x_1^2 + y_1^2) = p(p + 2d^{2}x_{1}y_{1}) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
If there's any prime $q \neq p$ where $q \mid d$, then the LHS has at least $3$ factors of $q$ but since $q \nmid p$, and $q\mid 2d^{2}x_{1}y_{1}$ so $q \nmid p + 2d^{2}x_{1}y_{1}$, then the RHS has no factors of $q$. If $p \mid d$ so $d = pd_1$, then substituting this into \eqref{eq3A} and dividing both sides by $p^2$ results in $pd_1^3(x_1 + y_1)(x_1^2 + y_1^2) = 1 + 2pd_1^{2}x_{1}y_{1}$, where $p$ is a factor of the LHS but not the RHS. Thus, this is also not possible, so there are no prime factors of $d$, i.e., we have
$$\gcd(x, y) = 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
Next, consider if
$$p \mid x + y \;\;\to\;\; x + y = jp, \, j \ge 1 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$
Due to symmetry, WLOG have $x \ge y$. Also, substituting \eqref{eq5A} into \eqref{eq1A} and multiplying both sides by $\frac{j}{p}$ then results in
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
j^2(x^2 + y^2) & = x + y + 2jxy \\
(j^2 - 1)x^2 + x^{2} - 2jxy + j^{2}y^2 & = x + y \\
(x - jy)^2 & = x - (j^2 - 1)x^2 + y \\
(x - jy)^2 & = x(1  - (j^2 - 1)x) + y
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$
Note that if $j = 1$, then \eqref{eq6A} becomes
$$(x - y)^2 = x + y = p \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$
which is not possible as no prime is a perfect square. However, if $j \ge 2$, then the RHS of \eqref{eq6A} is $\le -2x + y \lt 0$, which is not possible as the LHS is a perfect square.
Thus, we have that $p \nmid x + y$. Note this means that $p \neq 2$ since, if it were this value, then with the parity of $x + y$ and $x^2 + y^2$ being the same, we also have $p \nmid x^2 + y^2$, which is not allowed. Thus, $p$ must be an odd prime, meaning that the RHS of \eqref{eq1A} is odd, and thus one of $x$ and $y$ is odd while the other is even.
There are at least $2$ ways to prove that $p \nmid x^2 + y^2$. For both cases shown below, by contradiction, consider that
$$p \mid x^2 + y^2 \;\;\to\;\; x^2 + y^2 = kp, \, k \ge 1 \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

For the first method, substitute \eqref{eq8A} into \eqref{eq1A} and multiply both sides by $\frac{k}{p}$ to get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
k^2(x + y) & = x^2 + y^2 + 2kxy \\
k^2(x + y) & = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 + 2kxy - 2xy \\
k^2(x + y) - (x + y)^2 & = 2xy(k - 1) \\
(x + y)(k^2 - (x + y)) & = 2xy(k - 1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$
Note that $k = 1$ means the RHS is $0$, so $1 = x + y$ on the LHS, which is not possible for positive $x$ and $y$. Thus, $k \ge 3$ is an odd integer (actually, $k \equiv 1\pmod{4}$, as Aig's comment suggests), so $k - 1$ is even. We have from $\gcd(x, y) = 1$ that $\gcd(x + y, 4xy) = 1$, so
$$x + y \mid \frac{k - 1}{2} \;\;\to\;\; x + y \le \frac{k - 1}{2} \lt \frac{k}{2} \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$
Squaring both sides and using \eqref{eq8A} gives
$$kp = x^2 + y^2 \lt x^2 + 2xy + y^2 \lt \frac{k^2}{4} \;\;\to\;\; p \lt \frac{k}{4} \tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$
If $p \ge \frac{x + y}{2}$, then squaring both sides we get
$$p^2 \ge \frac{x^2 + 2xy + y^2}{4} \gt \frac{x^2 + y^2}{4} = \frac{pk}{4} \;\;\to\;\; p \gt \frac{k}{4} \tag{12}\label{eq12A}$$
However, this contradicts \eqref{eq11A}, so this means
$$p \lt \frac{x + y}{2} \;\;\to\;\; x + y = rp, \, r \in \mathbb{Q}, r \gt 2 \tag{13}\label{eq13A}$$
Using the similar approach as in \eqref{eq6A}, we then get
$$(x - ry)^2 = x(1  - (r^2 - 1)x) + y \tag{14}\label{eq14A}$$
which is also not possible as the LHS is a perfect square but the RHS is negative.

The second method to show that $p \nmid x^2 + y^2$ is based on the big hint given in triviality's comment. From \eqref{eq8A}, we get
$$x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \;\;\to\;\; (x + y)^2 \equiv 2xy \pmod{p} \tag{15}\label{eq15A}$$
However, substituting \eqref{eq8A} into \eqref{eq1A} and dividing both sides by $p$ gives that
$$k(x + y) \equiv 2xy \pmod{p} \tag{16}\label{eq16A}$$
Since $p \nmid x + y$, it has a multiplicative inverse of $(x + y)^{-1}$ modulo $p$, so multiplying both sides of \eqref{eq15A} and \eqref{eq16A} by this gives
$$2xy(x + y)^{-1} \equiv k \equiv x + y \pmod{p} \;\to\; k = x + y + mp, \, m \in \mathbb{Z} \tag{17}\label{eq17A}$$
Using this in \eqref{eq8A} results in
$$x^2 + y^2 = (x + y + mp)p \tag{18}\label{eq18A}$$
Substituting this into \eqref{eq1A}, and dividing both sides by $p$, we get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(x + y)(x + y + mp) & = p + 2xy \\
(x + y)^2 + mp(x + y) & = p + 2xy \\
x^2 + y^2 & = p(1 - m(x + y))
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{19}\label{eq19A}$$
Comparing \eqref{eq18A} with \eqref{eq19A} then gives that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x + y + mp & = 1 - m(x + y) \\
(m + 1)(x + y) & = 1 - mp
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{20}\label{eq20A}$$
If $m = 0$, we then get $x + y = 1$, which is not possible for positive $x$ and $y$. If $m \gt 0$, then the LHS is positive while the RHS is negative and, similarly, if $m \lt 0$, then the LHS is non-positive while the RHS is positive. As such, all cases show that \eqref{eq20A} is not possible.

Thus, using either of the $2$ methods above, we get that $p \nmid x^2 + y^2$. Since $p$ doesn't divide either of the factors on the LHS in \eqref{eq1A}, this means there are no solutions to it.

Thanks a lot for your time! I took some time to understand it fully and I think I got most of it. I just have one more question. how did you conclude (17) ?

@AbdelrahmanYousf You're welcome. Regarding $(17)$, I've updated my answer to add some more details. In particular, by multiplying both sides of the results in $(15)$ and $(16)$ by $(x+y)^{-1}$, then a factor of $x+y$ is removed from the LHS, and since the RHS were the same, this leaves that $k\equiv x+y\pmod{p}$. Then, by definition, we have that $p\mid k-(x+y);\to;k-(x+y)=mp;\to;k=x+y+mp$ for some integer $m$.
